# What does it mean to "send a contract calldata"?

Tags: solidity, calldata, bridge

While reading this [blog](https://blog.li.fi/connext-network-a-deep-dive-13ce31586fe7) about Connext.Network, I encountered with the following sentence:

> Connext is an interoperability protocol that allows users to send fast, fully non-custodial transfers or contract calldata between Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) -compatible chains and/or rollups

I'm new to bridages and Connext.Network so it will be great if you can help me understand the above sentence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It means it can transfer messages between different blockchains and smart contracts. Thus, a smart contract from one chain can call a contract on another.